# No swap on Manjaro

Tags: filesystems, swap, manjaro

So I recently installed Manjaro, used default installation options, and installed it on a partition of nearly 275GiB. I have a low end device with only 4 GB of RAM space. My device is usually slow so I used **htop**. I got this:

[image]

So I used **fdisk -l** to check all the partitions. This is the output:

[image]

Does no swap partition cause any problems? How can I solve this?

Comment: Didn't it ask you for swap partition at the time of installation

Comment: Nope. All it said was to choose a partition. It created all the filesystems automatically.

Comment: I don't have a swap partition. **swapon** need swap partition to enable or disable, isn't it??

Comment: If you have GUI then shrink one partition using gparted and make new unallocated space as swap partition

Comment: Keep in mind that swap could make things slower if it ends up thrashing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having no swap partition might be a problem if you try to set the machine to sleep. What you can do is:

1. boot on a live cd
2. shrink one of this partitions using something like gparted
3. create a swap partition
   Then you need to add the swap partition to fstab.
   To discover its UUID do:

ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

Then add the following line to fstab:

```
UUID=<swap partition uudid> swap           swap    defaults,noatime,discard 0       0
```

If you are afraid of messing the partitions you might consider creating a swap file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=512
# chmod 600 /swapfile
# mkswap /swapfile
# swapon /swapfile
```

Then add it to fstab:

```
/etc/fstab
/swapfile none swap defaults 0 0
```

Comment: link to Manjaro's wiki for reference: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Add_a_/swapfile